# GridView show all records in a list of objects containing a list

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

If have 2 types, A and B

```
class A 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<B> Children { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public A Parent { get; set; }
}
```

In my view model I have a `List<A> Items;`

I want to bind a grid view so there is is 1 row for event B showing the `A.Name` e.g.

```
A.Name       B.Name
  A1           B1
  A1           B2
  A1           B3
  A2           B1
  A3         {NULL}
```

However, like on A3, if the `List<B> Children` is empty, I still want to see the row for A.

The only thing I can think of is to have a 3rd type, e.g. C that contains the 2 strings and write code to make a list of them and bind to that, I was just hoping that there would be a better way.

I did think that I could use `Items.SelectMany(a => a.B);` and then use `Parent.Name` however this won't include the A items where Children is empty.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need a DataGrid?
It looks like you are doing something hierarchial so I would use a treeview or what do you exactly want to do... I think I can t understand you so you may give me a better example

Comment: It is basically a tree view but instead of having a root node that expands to show the children, I want the root node repeating on each line.